# DOMstring parser

Tags: javascript, dom, xmlhttprequest, web

I have a DOMstring object, text of some web page which I get from server using XMLHttpRequest. I need to cut a substring from it, which lies between some specific tags. Is there any easy way to do this? Such methods as substring() or slice() won't work in my case, because content of the web page is dynamic, so I can't specify the beginning and the end of substring (I only know that it's surrounded by `<tag>` and `</tag>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DOMString is just implemented as a string in most (all?) JavaScript browser environments so you can use any parsing technique you like, including regular expressions, DOMParser, and the HTML parser provided by libraries such as jQuery.  For example:

```javascript
function extractText(domString) {
  var m = (''+domString).match(/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/i);
  return (m) ? m[0] : null;
}
```

Of course, this is a terrible idea; you should really use a DOM parser, for example, with jQuery:

```javascript
$('tag', htmlString).html();
```

**[Edit]** To clarify the above jQuery example, it's the equivalent of doing something like below:

```javascript
function extractText2(tagName, htmlString) {
  var div = document.createElement('div'); // Build a DOM element.
  div.innerHTML = htmlString; // Set its contents to the HTML string.
  var el = div.getElementsByTagName(tagName) // Find the target tag.
  return (el.length > 0) ? el[0].textContent : null; // Return its contents.
}
extractText2('tag', '<tag>Foo</tag>'); // => "Foo"
extractText2('x', '<x><y>Bar</y></x>'); // => "Bar"
extractText2('y', '<x><y>Bar</y></x>'); // => "Bar"
```

This solution is better than a regex solution since it will handle any HTML syntax nuances on which the regex solution would fail.  Of course, it likely needs some cross-browser testing, hence the recommendation to a library like jQuery (or Prototype, ExtJS, etc).

Comment: Thanks, your and some other advices work. But it seems like some kind of a "hack" when you cut string according to some words in it. Generally, content of the page may change and code won't work. Is there any way to recieve html page as, f.e., xml-document, and then just take required element from it?

Comment: it's what he is doing with that `$('tag', domString).html();` . It gets the content of the tag element in the string 'domString' which is implicitly converted to a dom element. With jQuery $(aXMLString) will return a dom element. ( i think it is writed with innerHTML in a created element and returned via element.getChildren() )

Answer (score 2):

```
yourString.subtring(yourString.indexOf('<tag>') + 5, yourString.indexOf('</tag>'));
```

This should work, assuming you know the name of the surrounding tags.

Comment: substring is missing an s

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the surrounding tag is unique in the string...

```
domString.match(/.*<tag>(.*)<\/tag>.*/)[0]
```

or

```
/.*<tag>(.*)<\/tag>.*/.exec(domString)[0]
```

Seems like it should do the trick

Comment: isn't that String.match(Regex) instead of Regex.match(string) ?

Comment: Opps, yes one of the lovely eclectic features of javascript is that test is on the expression, but match is on the string :). Editing to fix now

Answer (score 0):

As @Gus but improved, if you only have text and the tags are repited:

```
"<tag>asd</tag>".match(/<tag>[^<]+<\/tag>/);
```

Comment: Not improved. This doesn't work. If your string is "<tag>string within the tag</tag>"  You get "g". If one adds the missing * to your expression to make it `/[^<]*</tag>/` then it still deosn't work because you get "tag>string within the tag" I probably could remove my extraneous .*'s I tend to do that because I write regex as I think it and I thought "anything, tag, anything endtag anything" :). I'm  pretty sure most regexp engines just lop these off anyway however.

Comment: damn the editor broke it and I didn't realized :-/, what about this updated version?

Comment: Works only if the content doesn't contain a tag. Also, if it contains no data, you will not match at all, and I think that may cause an error when you try to dereference it.

Comment: well, as I said, if the content is only text. And why do you say that it may cause an error?